# Optimize of hibernate delete operation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

The code below works but have performance issues when the SQL deletes more than a million rows. It takes a very long time for 2M tables to be deleted approx 1 hr. We don't have control on the sql condition passed to us. Is there a better way to make this run faster?

Apart from this we don't have DB admin access so stored procedures can't be a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

SAMPLE SQL QUERY

```
DELETE TBL_A WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TBL_B WHERE 1=1 AND TBL_B.BD < TO_DATE(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -240)));
```

DELETE METHOD

```
 public void deleteRows(String table, String condition){

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("DELETE TABLE=:TABLE WHERE CONDITION=:CONDITION ");

    try{
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    int rows = session.createSQLQuery(sql.toString()).setParamater("TABLE",TABLE).setParameter("CONDITION",CONDITION).executeUpdate();

    transaction.commit();
    }
    catch{
    //logic here
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no faster way for this specific "issue". Unfortunately, it is not a performance issue, it is an application design issue.

... BUT ...

You can:

1. Create a list-partitioned replica of the table with a single partition and a set of indexes identical to the original table.
2. Use `insert /*+ append */ into the replica select * from the original` table with `NOT` of the `CONDITION`.
3. Swap the single replica partition with the original table.
4. `Truncate` the single replica partition with `drop storage` option.

More specific answer would require a much more specific question.

Comment: thanks nop, so the only way we optimize the performance of delete operation of our app is by changing the SQL condition itself right?

Comment: Not quite. What I suggested is that instead of deleting a large amount of rows via DELETE you can use the "DWH"-like approach and insert the complementary rows (via direct-load!) into a different table, and then swap the two tables (via partition exchange).

But, generally, the final solution is, really, very dependent on what amounts of data we are talking about, what options of doing table organization changes you have, etc. etc. :-(

Comment: Also, for that particular sample query you posted in your question ...

Try creating indexes on `TBL_B (BD, ID)` and on `TBL_A (ID)`, if you you don't yet have those, and have the statistics on `TBL_A` and `TBL_B` recomputed. That might help a potentially suboptimal execution plan for the query.

Alas, without knowing your application, all of the execution plans being used, your table structures and data volumes I can't suggest solutions to your performance problem(s).